# Calculationd for TfidfVectorizer()

Tags: python, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am using TfidfVectorizer() to convert the text to a numeric vector which I can use as independent variable to train the model.

I have tried to convert the text string to vector using TfidfVectorizer()

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer()
Tfidf_vect.fit(main['Description'])
```

Input strings are -
Description-

```
Harry FEEL'N LEA.MEGA CEL FILL.2T-3T
Harry potter JUMBO CEL #1 COUCHES
```

vectoriser Output generated is -

```
->print(Tfidf_vect.vocabulary_)
{'Harry': 9, 'potter': 10, 'jumbo': 6, 'cel': 2, 'couches': 3, 'feel': 4, 
 'lea': 7, 'mega': 8, 'fill': 5, '2t': 0, '3t': 1}

=>print(Train_X_Tfidf)
  (0, 9)        0.26868527618515564
  (0, 8)        0.37762778074064174
  (0, 7)        0.37762778074064174
  (0, 5)        0.37762778074064174
  (0, 4)        0.37762778074064174
  (0, 2)        0.26868527618515564
  (0, 1)        0.37762778074064174
  (0, 0)        0.37762778074064174
  (1, 10)       0.4992213265230509
  (1, 9)        0.35520008546852583
  (1, 6)        0.4992213265230509
  (1, 3)        0.4992213265230509
  (1, 2)        0.35520008546852583
```

Please explain how 0.26868527618515564 value is generated for Harry word in first sentence.

Comment: There's a good description of how TF-IDF is calculated at www.tfidf.com

Comment: Following values obtained from formula on the www.tfidf.com is not matching with the values obtained from code. 
For Harry- 
tf = 1/8 = 0.125
idf = log(2/2)+1 = 1
vectoriser output = 0.125.
But code output is 0.26868527618515564